# Click once Winform App - Exception Strong name signature

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, publish, signature

I am new to programming and am running into an error when trying to publish my winform app using Click once. The error I am getting is

"   Following errors were detected during this operation.
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
        - Strong name signature not valid for this assembly MetroFramework.dll.
"

Now when creating my project, I wasn't able to change some of the colors and fonts of Metro controls, so I altered the DLL to change the default colors. I think this is causing the problem?

The whole purpose of using click once, was to get the "auto update" functionality" in place. Previously I was using the setup project, and end users at our firm were going to a shared network drive and re-installing the app each time an update is made. I was hoping to implement click once so that I could have the app automatically update, and to restrict end users from using older versions of the app.

I really don't think I am going to figure this out with my level of knowledge, despite how many searches I do..

---

I'd like to clarify what I am experiencing at the same time:

My app is for coworkers to use and connects to our main database. I am able to successfully deploy the project by adding and building a "Setup Project". This allows me to make the MSI and create icons and so forth. I am placing the setup file in a network drive where end users can find and install the app.

Everything is great from start to finish, except how I am handling software updates. Currently users ask for a change, I go and update the app and place the new setup file in the network drive. The problem with this is:
1) Users aren't automatically advised an update is available
2) Users aren't required to update the software.. they can continue using the version they have (which is bad).

So I was looking for a way to ensure users are prompted to update to the latest version when it is available. Heading down this road, I found in a search that I could use the "click once" deployment method (instead of setup project) to implement auto updates.

My two problems are:
A) I don't even know if this is the best approach to achieve the objective outlined above.
B) When I try using "click one" to publish, I am able to publish but I am NOT able to run the setup exe afterward. I am getting the MetroFramework "Strong name signature not valid for this assembly MetroFramework.dll." LIke I mentioned I think this may be because I altered the DLL to gain control of the fonts. But I have no idea how to even start to go about rectifying this..

Answer (score 0):

Are you struggling with making the installer with Click Once? You could try and make one in Windows Forms which I have done in the past. What I have done for Automatic Updates is host a file on my website which the application downloads each time and when I release the update I change the file content to the location of the auto installer (Which is WinForms) for it to download and run. This may be a good solution for you. My experience with `MetroFramework.dll` was not great and I ended up just giving up on using it. The `MetroFramework.dll` file must also be in the same directory as the executable file in order for it to work which is something to keep in mind when creating an installer. Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ProudAviator, it is very encouraging and I greatly appreciate it. I re-wrote my question above, in hopes that it clarifies your question.